# Quasi Fixed Input

Tags: input-output

What is quasi fixed cost? What is the difference between fixed and quasi-fixed cost? Is capital, land and labour considered a quasi fixed cost for a firm? I have read that when the firm wants to take new labours, it can face a higher wage, then it is a quasi fixed cost but it seems to me that it should come under variable cost as the input cost changes with the quantity of output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your question? "I have read" is not very helpful.

Comment: This is the reference where I read it "http://courses.missouristate.edu/reedolsen/courses/eco310/equasi.pdf" It is a paper which I browsed online.

Answer (score 1):

*Quasi-fixed labour costs* are typically those associated with the number of workers rather than the number of hours they work, so things like

- recruitment costs
- training costs

Commonly they are seen as fixed costs in the short run, but marginal costs in the long run.

Other non-labour costs which have the same short run / long run distinction can also be seen as *quasi-fixed costs*